# databinding to a int list "windows phone 8"

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am trying to bind to `List<int>`, so the number of items equals List.Count, and each item is a Rectangle with Width of List[i].

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> 
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Azure"/>
                  </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Could anyone provide a tutorial about multi-level databinding and triggers ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Bind your ListBox, ItemsControl, or whatever, to the list, then bind the width of your rectangle to the current item (by setting an empty binding expression): `<Rectangle Width="{Binding}" />`

Comment: thanks it work! bind to the current object( by setting an empty binding expression) .

Comment: Posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is. Bind your ListBox, ItemsControl, or whatever, to the list, then bind the width of your rectangle to the current item (by setting an empty binding expression):

```
<Rectangle Width="{Binding}" />
```